# How best to extract specific values from a large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Give the sample dataframe below (the actual list of sites and servers per site is very large), how would I extract/print the single DSKPERCENT_MEAN value per site?

```
Site  Server           DSKPERCENT      DSKPERCENT_MEAN
A      1                12                 11
A      2                10                 11
A      3                11                 11
B      1                9                  9
B      2                12                 9
B      3                7                  9
C      1                12                 13
C      2                12                 13
C      3                16                 13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to(?):

```
df.groupby('Site')['DSKPERCENT_MEAN'].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['Site'])['DSKPERCENT_MEAN'].mean()
```

Comment: @Subbu wont this command calculate the mean based on the 'Site' and 'DSKPERCENT' groupby?  I have already calculated the DSKPERCENT_MEAN, I just need to extract the unique calculated mean value for each site

Comment: @odonnry Modified the answer to fetch the unique values from DSKPERCENT_MEAN

Answer (score 0):

Further from Serial Lazer's answer. I suppose you don't need to add another column of ['DSKPERCENT_MEAN'] since all sites has the same mean. If you want to create a new DataFrame that yields only the mean of DSKPERCENT, I suggest using code below:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Site')['DSKPERCENT'].mean().to_frame(name='DSKPERCENT_MEAN').reset_index()
```

.to_frame(name = 'DSKPERCENT_MEAN') lets you create a new DataFrame out of the Groupby result
.reset_index() resets the column 'DSKPERCENT_MEAN' into the same row as 'Site'

df1's output:

```
     Site   DSKPERCENT_MEAN
0    A      11
1    B      9
2    C      13
```